# Can't debug this simple SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax

I'm importing data into a MySQL table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
I.ve done this on another table without difficulty, and I copied the stmt and just changed the table name and the fields. Here's the statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/John/league_seasons.csv'
INTO TABLE lwl_league_players
IGNORE 1 LINES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(id, location_id, game_id, league_season_id, player_id);
```

Here's the error:

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(id, location_id, game_id,' at line 4
```

The FIELDS TERMINATED BY and LINES TERMINATED BY lines are exactly the same as my previously working statement. I've checked the structure and it's fine.

[image: Table Structure]

I'd appreciate someone pointing out where I'm screwing up.  Thanks

Comment: When I look this command up, the `IGNORE *N* LINES` clause seems to come after the `FIELDS` and `LINES` clauses. It's not clear if this matters, but it often does. Could you try it with that clause moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the options matter.

Once you placed `IGNORE 1 LINES`, the next thing should be the list of columns.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/John/league_seasons.csv'
INTO TABLE lwl_league_players
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, location_id, game_id, league_season_id, player_id);
```

See the [MySQL Documentation on the syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) and you will see the correct order for the options.